# update data only if state changes with react

Tags: reactjs

I have a `User` component and I want to make an api call to update the `inactive` state.

The problem that I´m having is that the `useEffect` is being called when the component receives `props`. That means it will make the call when component renders for the first time. What´s the pattern to avoid this and only make the call if `inactive` state changes?

My initial try was to remove user from the dependencies array. But I need to get the `user.id` to pass it to the service.

What´s the pattern to avoid making these unnecessary calls?

```
const User = (props) => {

    const { user } = props
    const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(user.inactive);

    useEffect(() => {

        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const data = { inactive: Number(inactive) }

        updateUserRecordInDatabase(user.id, data);

        return () => {
            abortController.abort();
        };

    }, [inactive, user])

    return (
        <button onClick={ () => setInactive(!inactive) } />toggle { user.name } state</button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const User = (props) => {

    const { user } = props
    const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(user.inactive);
    const [numUpdate, setNumUpdate] = useState(0);
    const {id} = user //You get id of use here
    useEffect(() => {
        if(numUpdate === 0){
          // This is first time of useEffect
          setNumUpdate(numUpdate + 1); // Only update when first time of useEffect
        }
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const data = { inactive: Number(inactive) }

        updateUserRecordInDatabase(id, data);

        return () => {
            abortController.abort();
        };

    }, [inactive, id])

    return (
        <button onClick={ () => setInactive(!inactive) } />toggle { user.name } state</button>
    )
}
```